# Method not working when called from another class Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, class, methods

I have the following method in my app.

```
- (void)next{
    NSLog(@"called!");
    NSArray *visibleItems = [self.collectionView indexPathsForVisibleItems];
    NSIndexPath *currentItem = [visibleItems objectAtIndex:0];
    NSIndexPath *nextItem = [NSIndexPath indexPathForItem:currentItem.item + 1 inSection:currentItem.section];
    [self.collectionView scrollToItemAtIndexPath:nextItem atScrollPosition:UICollectionViewScrollPositionCenteredHorizontally animated:YES];

    CATransition *fadeTextAnimation = [CATransition animation];
    fadeTextAnimation.duration = 0.2;
    fadeTextAnimation.type = kCATransitionFade;

    [self.navigationController.navigationBar.layer addAnimation: fadeTextAnimation forKey: @"fadeText"];
    self.navigationItem.title = @"Test";
}
```

It is working great when I call it from the class it is implemented in. However if I call it from another class, the NSLog works fine, but nothing else happens. I guess it has to do something with `self.collectionView` not actually referencing my `collectionView` when called from another class, but I have no idea how to solve the issue. Can you please point me in the right direction?

**EDIT:** This is how I call my method from another class.

```
ExerciseViewController *vc;
[vc next];
```

The method gets called fine, because NSLog works, it just that the rest of the code is not executed properly.

**EDIT 2:** I changed the code to

```
UIStoryboard *mainStoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle: nil];
ExerciseViewController *controller = [mainStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier: @"id"];
[controller next];
```

However, still, only NSLog works. Any thoughts?

Comment: What does the code look like where you're calling this method?  (Specifically, are you using and existing instance of the method's class or creating a new instance?)

Comment: @PhillipMills Edited the question!

Comment: If `next` is actually being executed that means that you must be assigning something to `vc` somewhere.  It would be interesting to know what that "something" is and how it's created.

Answer (score 3):

```
ExerciseViewController *vc;
[vc next];
```

You only declare the view controller, you don't instantiate an object.

`vc` is nil, and nil can accept any message, there for this doesn't lead to a crash.

---

```
ExerciseViewController *vc = [[ExerciseViewController alloc] init];
```

will also not create the View Controller as design in the storyboard, you have to instantiate from the storyboard.

---

after you created your `vc` object, you will have to display it on the screen. i.e. push it to a view controller to present it. You will find tons of example codes. you just need to search for it. also it seems like you did not invest much time on https://developer.apple.com. have a look on their guides. Now!

Comment: Hi! It still does not work if i do `ExerciseViewController *vc = [[ExerciseViewController alloc] init];`

Comment: did u design it by nib or storyboard?

Comment: By storyboard, but the method is called fine, I don't think that the problem is what you think it is. However, I will try!

Comment: you need to instantiate from storyboard, than your vc will be visible.

Comment: But if a message was actually being logged inside `next` before he added the alloc/init...?

Comment: @vikingosegundo Can you show me some code, after several trials, I am not sure I understand

Comment: i am in a hurry, but search for "UIViewcontroller instantiate from storyboard"